# Browser can't find font when the website is published on azure

Tags: css, azure

I noticed an error after I published on azure.

The browser can't find the font at
`http://mydummywebsite/Content/KaneLandingPage/assets/elegant-icons/fonts/ElegantIcons.svg`

but when I look on the ftp server, the file is there.

```
ftp://mydummywebsite.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/Content/KaneLandingPage/assets/elegant-icons/fonts/ElegantIcons.svg
```

Here is the css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ElegantIcons';
    src:url(/Content/KaneLandingPage/assets/elegant-icons/fonts/ElegantIcons.eot);
    src:url(/Content/KaneLandingPage/assets/elegant-icons/fonts/ElegantIcons.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
        url(/Content/KaneLandingPage/assets/elegant-icons/fonts/ElegantIcons.ttf) format('truetype'),
        url(/Content/KaneLandingPage/assets/elegant-icons/fonts/ElegantIcons.svg#ElegantIcons) format('svg'),
        url(/Content/KaneLandingPage/assets/elegant-icons/fonts/ElegantIcons.woff) format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Edit:

the `ElegantIcons.svg` is the only file I can't download from the ftp server.

And I don't have the error in IE because it opens the `ElegantIcons.eot`. The problem is with Chrome

Comment: Are you testing it from a localhost:// server or just trying to load the page locally?

Comment: It works on localhost, but it doesn't on the azure website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing IIS doesn't know how to serve the file.  You can try adding this to web.config...

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      </staticContent>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I needed. Could you explain the image/svg+xml part plz. It works also for the .woff but I just don't understand how it works.

Comment: It's the registered standard for .svg files.  http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/mimereg.html